# Pack two spring boot application in one jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, spring-boot, executable-jar

I have two different spring boot apps - client and server. I use maven and pack this applications into two executable .jar files - client.jar and server.jar. It would be great to create one executable file (.jar or .exe) which would run this two applications sequentially - it would run server.jar first and then it would run client.jar, is it possible in a way?

Thanks, cheers

Comment: Why not have a single jar and run server or client depending on a command line argument? You can always make an script to execute both and you give the end-user the liberty to run whatever he wants.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to have more then one applications in one jar. Auto-configuration is very sensitive to dependencies. Spring Boot makes own estimations about application based on those dependencies.
I had two classes annotated with @SpringBootApplication in one jar file. Spring Boot did not initialize database with my data.xml file.